# PDF, DOC and Execl to image conversion tool for web application

Tags: image, pdf, doc

can you please suggest some web tool (will provide DLL) to convert doc, excel and PDF to image at minimum cost. i m a dot.net developer and need to implement these feature in my web application....

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are in .NET, doc and xls can be easily opened by calling instances of Word and Excel. Once application instances are created and files loaded, you can perform a variety of operations including capturing screenshots (if you can work with 72 dpi resolution).

Comment: yes, this seems to be solution, but this all need to be done in background and screen is not visible to user. Is is possible to capture the doc file running in background. file must be image and will doc open in same format as original. can we capture only the opened doc file content not full screen??

Comment: Automating Office apps on the server is definitely *not* recommended. Even if you do that, you can't take a "screen shot" because the ASPNET user has no display and COM objects run in the background. The OP could theoretically use the Print function to print to a TIFF file, then convert that in .NET to PNG for display, but again, automation is not recommended.